# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - error

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection

I'm trying to insert in an Access Database, from visual C#. But i got this error: [error](http://img24.imageshack.us/i/errye.jpg/)

What am I doing wrong in code? The values are correct, they comes from the input boxes.

Thanks!

Comment: I would help if you paste your code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the picture it looks like the adapter.InsertCommand property is null.
Instead of

```
adapter.Insertcommand.CommandText = ...
```

use

```
insertCommand.CommandText = ...
adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the `OleDbDataAdapter adapter` ok, and you're creating a (stand-alone) `OleDbCommand insertCommand` as well - but you're **NOT** creating an instance for `adapter.InsertCommand` - that variable will be NULL !

You need to do:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand();
```

Create the `adapter.InsertCommand` instead of a stand-alone instance.

Comment: Thanks! But why the data is not saved in the database? I have set this:    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Admitere.mdb";   , and Admitere.mdb is in my local c# project folder..

Comment: I would post a new question for that.

Comment: @qwerty: if your `adapter.InsertCommand` is NULL and not present - how should the adapter be able to insert data???

Answer (score 0):

At bottom left of picture I see "adapter.InserCommand" is null while the error occurred after you created a new "oleDbCommand" and it's the source of exception. Why ? Because you created one "oleDbCommand" and didn't assign it to your adapter.

Anyway, the way you deal with sql is not recommended and the code is prone to sql injection attacks.
Also putting a large amount of code inside a "Try" block is not recommended since you cannot find the source of problem later.